When combining obj files, one of them gets weirdly distorted
I am trying to convert two obj files: a generic head without a face and a rudimentary face.
When I display the face by itself (in its own file), its fine. Same for head. But when I combined the 2, the face becomes very distorted!


I am combining the 2 obj files through code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KlmV7lG0A992T01vXUaQOVbVQdXPxuRf/view?usp=sharing
Basically I'm just appending them together but where I use o to define each object. So I'd write o head and below it are the vertices and faces of head. Then after I'd write o face and below it are the vertices and faces of face.
In theory the file seems fine. Why is it doing this? Could it be because there are overlapping vertices? If i cut the part of the face from the combined obj file and pasted it elsewhere, the face looks completely fine too! so I'm assuming the combining is what's causing the problem.

You can't just append .obj files together. The list of vertices in an OBJ is global, not per-object, so to append them changes the vertex indices. Why don't you just import both .obj separately?

Hello. Could you share the script as text in your question ? Thanks
